# Nancy basic auth password change causes authentication to fail

Tags: basic-authentication, nancy

I have created a self-hosting site using Nancy and Owin. I used Nancy.BasicAuthentication for authentication. Everything works fine until I change the current logged in user's password.

Once the password is changed, if the user creates a request then they are redirected to the 404 error page and the window pops up asking for a username and password.

How can I update the user's credentials after a password change to stop them from losing authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Basic auth is very easy to listen in on - consider digest auth instead.

b) Both basic auth and digest auth work on a page by page basis - every request is authenticated individually (the browser just automates the authentication if it already has the credentials)

c) Hopefully a 401 Authentication Required, not a 404 Not Found is returned?

d) I suspect doing anything to allow a previously authenticated user to continue using a site after the password is changed (e.g. cookies) would require code changes to the authentication handler. You could for example set a cookie (crypto required) when a page is successfully authenticated, then not require authentication for further pages if the cookie is available (with a timeout on the cookie).